# multivariate p.d.f. and distribution

Tags: matrices, probability-distributions

> Suppose $X\sim N(\mu,V)$ where
>
> $\mu = \begin{pmatrix}
> 2 \\
> 2 \\
> 2
> \end{pmatrix}$
>
> $V = \begin{pmatrix}
> 3 & 2 & 1 \\
> 2& 4 & 1 \\
> 1 & 1 & 2
> \end{pmatrix}$
>
> a) Write down the p.d.f of $X$
>
> b) Find the distribution of $AX$ where $A= \begin{pmatrix}
> 2 & -1 & -1 \\
> 0 & 1 & -1 \\
> \end{pmatrix}$
>
> c) Find the distribution of $BX$ where $B= \begin{pmatrix}
> 1 & 1 & 1 \\
> 1 & -1 & 0 \\
> 0 & 1 & -1 \\
> \end{pmatrix}$
>
> d) Find the marginal distributions of $(X_1,X_2)$ and of $X_3$

for a) I have

$ f(x) =$ $ 1 \over(2\pi)^{3/2} |V|^{1/2}$$e^{-1/2(x-\mu)^TV^-1(x-\mu)}$

I don't know if it's right

b) mean: $\begin{pmatrix}
2 & -1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & -1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$\begin{pmatrix}
2\\
2\\
2\\
\end{pmatrix}=$$\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
\end{pmatrix}$

covariance: $\begin{pmatrix}
2 & -1 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & -1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$
$\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 2 & 1 \\
2 & 4 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 2 \\
\end{pmatrix}$
$\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0 \\
-1 & 1 \\
-1 & -1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$=\begin{pmatrix}
8 & 0 \\
0 & 4 \\
\end{pmatrix}$

$AX \sim N($$\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
\end{pmatrix},$$\begin{pmatrix}
8 & 0 \\
0 & 4 \\
\end{pmatrix})$

c) mean: $\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & -1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$\begin{pmatrix}
2\\
2\\
2\\
\end{pmatrix}=$$\begin{pmatrix}
6\\
0\\
0\\
\end{pmatrix}$

covariance: $\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & -1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$
$\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 2 & 1 \\
2 & 4 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 2 \\
\end{pmatrix}$
$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & -1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$=\begin{pmatrix}
17 & -1 & 3 \\
-1 & 3 & -2 \\
3 & -2 & 4 \\
\end{pmatrix}$

$BX \sim N($$\begin{pmatrix}
6\\
0\\
0\\
\end{pmatrix},$$\begin{pmatrix}
17 & -1 & 3 \\
-1 & 3 & -2 \\
3 & -2 & 4 \\
\end{pmatrix})$

d) $(X_1,X_2) \sim N($$\begin{pmatrix}
2 \\
2 \\
\end{pmatrix},$$\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 2 \\
2 & 4 \\
\end{pmatrix})$

$X_3 \sim N(2,2)$

Am I right?

Comment: Why doesn't $A$ and $V$ multiply? Moreover, in d) $(X_1,X_2)\sim N(4,11)$ makes no sense.

Comment: Nevermind, I was doing A^T V A, not A V A^T

Could you explain? That doesn't help me much without explanation :)

Comment: $(X_1,X_2)$ is a two-dimensional vector, $N(4,11)$ is the distribution of a one-dimensional variable.

Comment: You're right, thanks. I did $X_1 + X_2$. Edited: Is that better?

Comment: Yes, that looks correct.